# looping error in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

What I'm trying to achieve is let the user check some checkboxes and after that I'll do some actions on the checked items. I'm getting the below error in the below controller code :

Here is the error , it's complain about the line that contains **each**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot execute null+null
```

controller :

```
def activateSubscriptions (SubscriptionRequest subscriptionRequestInstance) {
    def temp
    println ("Params : $params.subscriptionRequestInstanceCheckBox , Count: $subscriptionRequestInstance.count()")

    params['subscriptionRequestInstanceCheckBox'].each  {
        temp =new Subscriptions(userId:subscriptionRequestInstance.userId,packageId:subscriptionRequestInstance.packageId,dasubscriptionRequestInstanceOfPackExp:subscriptionRequestInstance.dateCreated+30,balanceOfAds:Packages.get(subscriptionRequestInstance.packageId).numOfAds,
        balanceOfMsgs:Packages.get(subscriptionRequestInstance.packageId).numOfMsgs,balanceOfHR:Packages.get(subscriptionRequestInstance.packageId).numOfHR,balanceOfPages:Packages.get(subscriptionRequestInstance.packageId).numOfPages).save(flush:true)

        SubscriptionRequest.get(subscriptionRequestInstance.id).delete(flush:true)
    }
}
```

here is the GSP:

```
<g:each in="${subscriptionRequestInstanceList}" status="i" var="subscriptionRequestInstance">
    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
        <td>
            <g:checkBox checked="false" name='subscriptionRequestInstanceCheckBox' value="${subscriptionRequestInstance.id}"/> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <g:link action="show"  id="${subscriptionRequestInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: subscriptionRequestInstance, field: "userId")}</g:link>
        </td>
        <td>${fieldValue(bean: subscriptionRequestInstance, field: "packageId")}</td>
        <td><g:formatDate date="${subscriptionRequestInstance.dateCreated}" /></td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

Although the values from the `println` are :

```
Params : [1, 2] , Count: 2
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: It's unlikely the problem is on the line calling `each()`. Try commenting/uncommenting out the lines within the loop until you find the real offending line. My bet is on the LOOOOONG line creating the `Subscriptions`.

Answer (score 0):

This statement within the constructor looks to be the problem:

```
dasubscriptionRequestInstanceOfPackExp:subscriptionRequestInstance.dateCreated+30
```

If the goal is just to fix the exception, change it to:

```
dasubscriptionRequestInstanceOfPackExp: (subscriptionRequestInstance.dateCreated ? subscriptionRequestInstance.dateCreated + 30 : null)
```

This is assuming that the `dasubscriptionRequestInstanceOfPackExp` field is nullable, or you are ok with the save failing.

---

Rather than using `Packages.get(subscriptionRequestInstance.packageId)` over and over again, why not store it in a variable like this?  From the performance standpoint, it might be meaningless at this point but it cleans up the constructor arguments.

```
def activateSubscriptions (SubscriptionRequest subscriptionRequestInstance) {
    def temp
    println ("Params : $params.subscriptionRequestInstanceCheckBox , Count: $subscriptionRequestInstance.count()")

    def package = Packages.get(subscriptionRequestInstance.packageId)

    params.subscriptionRequestInstanceCheckBox.each  {
        temp = new Subscriptions(
            userId: subscriptionRequestInstance.userId,
            packageId: subscriptionRequestInstance.packageId,
            dasubscriptionRequestInstanceOfPackExp: subscriptionRequestInstance.dateCreated + 30,
            balanceOfAds: package.numOfAds,
            balanceOfMsgs: package.numOfMsgs,
            balanceOfHR: package.numOfHR,
            balanceOfPages: package.numOfPages
        ).save(flush:true)

        SubscriptionRequest.get(subscriptionRequestInstance.id).delete(flush:true)
    }
}
```